# Is there any alternate to cURL

Tags: php, curl, instamojo

I am currently working with instamojo payment gateway.

I have a payment ID for the same and using the following code to get the payment status

```
echo $cUrl = 'https://test.instamojo.com/api/1.1/payments/' . $payment_id;
                     (function_exists('curl_init')) ? '' : die('cURL Must be installed for geturl function to work. Ask your host to enable it or uncomment extension=php_curl.dll in php.ini');
                    $ch = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $cUrl);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Api-Key:90a1c44nmb8ac4e65nmnm3eab5b308cf",
                                                               "X-Auth-Token:8164083509a889951fhjhjh1ff89c4"));
                    $response = curl_exec($ch);
                    $error_number = curl_errno($ch);
                    $error_message = curl_error($ch);
                    curl_close($ch);
                    $response_obj = json_decode($response, true);
                    echo "Eror number: $error_number<br />";
                    echo "Eror message: $error_message<br />";
                    print_r($response_obj);

                    if($response_obj['success'] == false) {
                        $message = json_encode($response_obj['message']);
                        return Array('payment' => Array('status' => $message));

                    }
                    if(empty($response_obj) || is_null($response_obj)){
                        return Array('payment' => Array('status' => 'No response from the server.'));
                    }
                    else{
                        return $response_obj;
                    }
```

But When I am running this code on my localhost then I am getting the result properly.

But when I am running this on my server (i.e. 000webhost.com) but getting error :

```
Warning:  curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set in /home/a2963438/public_html/wp-content/plugins/instamojo-register/imojoregister_shortcode.php on line 18
```

I am using free account of 000webhost.com So I am unable to enable safe_mode or edit any `php.ini`.

So I want to ask that is there any other method to achieve the response of this url ?

Comment: Why not just follow the redirects yourself?

Comment: "You get what you pay for", comes to mind.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php with create_context

Comment: aah..."No free lunches!" You will have to upgrade server. Without `php.ini`, you won't be able to set `safe_mode = Off`

Answer (score 11):

You may want to have a look at Guzzle.

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html

According to their FAQ located here: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-guzzle-require-curl

Does Guzzle require cURL?

No. Guzzle can use any HTTP handler to send requests. This means that Guzzle can be used with cURL, PHP's stream wrapper, sockets, and non-blocking libraries like React. You just need to configure an HTTP handler to use a different method of sending requests.

Note

Guzzle has historically only utilized cURL to send HTTP requests. cURL is an amazing HTTP client (arguably the best), and Guzzle will continue to use it by default when it is available. It is rare, but some developers don't have cURL installed on their systems or run into version specific issues. By allowing swappable HTTP handlers, Guzzle is now much more customizable and able to adapt to fit the needs of more developers.

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to upgrade your server, means while u can use **[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)** in order get your things done