# Pure PHP How to Read Metatags of a remote url WITHOUT curl

Tags: javascript, php, meta-tags

I can see there are some similar questions on stackoverflow. but none seems to help. I am developing a site where users can add external links in chatbox etc. When they add an external url, I also want to show a preview, including title, and description. How can I do that. (I prefer doing that WITHOUT Curl) . Edit: In the title itself I have mentioned 'WITHOUT Curl' the reason is in my Xampp devp environment curl is NOT giving the desired result instead it says something like 'ssl wrapper not found.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522636/get-file-content-from-url

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get file content from URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522636/get-file-content-from-url)

Comment: @Ali Alwash : I am using Xampp and for some reason Curl is NOT giving the desired result. It says something like ssl wrapper NOT found

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40544807/is-there-any-alternate-to-curl

Comment: @DonR : I said I have no luck with curl. :-)

Comment: The answer to the question I linked specifically mentions that Guzzle does not require cURL. You really ought to read the link before replying.

Comment: What I mean by Pure PHP is NO GUZZLE_MUZZLE OR any such party spoilers